# Can you publish an npm package for a frontend JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

A client would like to use an npm package to access our JavaScript file's functions instead of adding a script tag to their html. Is this possible? The only resource I've come across for creating an npm package is for NodeJS files (https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).

Comment: So make an npm package for them to import and use the functions. What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but you cannot import the npm package and have it work in the browser without some sort of bundling system like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Alternatively, which is a bad idea, would be to ship your dist folder with `node_modules` in it. This isn't recommended for a multitude of reasons, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Following approach might be suitable for your client's requirement.

1. Create a NPM project using the javascript file you have
2. Publish it on client's Github account as a package.
3. Create a .npmrc file in root of your client's project.
4. Add your package in .npmrc file and in packages.json both.

Refer this doc for using a package with .npmrc file:
https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#installing-a-package).